# Downloading text of s3 file directly

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I have the following file I want to grab the text of:

https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/premiere-avails/movie.xsd.xml

Is there a way a better way to download it directly and store the contents other than:

```
import requests
contents = requests.get('https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/premiere-avails/movie.xsd.xml').text
```

Comment: How do you want your code to be better?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to download the file, you could use the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/):

```
aws s3 cp s3://premiere-avails/movie.xsd.xml movie.xsd.xml
```

Works for me!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use boto, try something like this (from the [boto documentation](https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/s3_tut.html)):

```
import boto
connection = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = connection.get_bucket('premiere-avails')
from boto.s3.key import Key
k = Key(bucket)
k.key = 'movie.xsd.xml'
k.get_contents_to_filename('movie.xsd.xml')
```